# Unexpected behaviour with generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm facing this error while work with Java generics, and I don't understand which is the problem;
I have two classes like these:

```
public abstract class BaseClass{
   ....
}

public class OneClass extends BaseClass{
   ....
}
```

I have a generic repo for OneClass:

```
public class MyRepo<T extends BaseClass>{
   List<T> getElements();
}
```

Then I have a method that should works whit generics:

```
private MyRepo<OneClass> myRepo;   

public <T extends BaseClass> List<T> myMethod(){
     return myRepo.getElements();
}
```

The method doesn't work unless I force a cast to List ( as shown below ):

```
public <T extends BaseClass> List<T> myMethod(){
   return  (List<T>)  myRepo.getElements();
}
```

I don't understand which is the problem given that OneClass extends BaseClass.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: The field `myRepo` is not generic. It is set to `MyRepo<OneClass>`. You basicly want it to be `MyRepo<T>` otherwise your function would only work with `OneClass` and you could remove the generics.

Answer (score 2):

Having a method of the form:

```java
<T> T myMethod()
```

makes the inference of the actual `T` dependent on the call-site:

```
String s = myMethod();
Integer i = myMethod();
```

Considering your scenario one could invoke your method like this:

```
List<BaseClass> a = myMethod();
List<OneClass> a = myMethod();
```

As you can see this can be incorrect as `myMethod` could actually return another subtype of `BaseClass` (lets say `TwoClass`) which is **not** correct to cast to `List<OneClass>` - thus you need the **unsafe** cast to `List<T>`.

You should change the signature of `myMethod` to one of the following:

```
public List<? extends BaseClass> myMethod(){}
public List<BaseClass> myMethod(){}
```

The first variant states that this is a list of any subtype of `BaseClass` the other just omits that information.

Dependent on what you want to achieve check the other answer or read about PECS (Producer Extends, Consumer Super) or f-bounded polymorphism / self-types to return the concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

Error message tells you that not every `T extends BaseClass` is `OneClass`

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the field `myRepo` is the same type as `T` as in your method. If you force it to be `OneClass` you cant use othere types except OneClass. So there is no use of a generic. If you want to allow every extending class from `BaseClass` you could make the class of the mehtod generic in oder to use the same type of `T` as shown below:

```
public class FunctionClass<T extends BaseClass> {
    private MyRepo<T> myRepo; 
        
    public List<T> myMethod(){
        return  myRepo.getElements();
    }
}
```